# Como trocar cores de forma dinâmica com JavaScript e CSS puro?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Meu objetivo é criar temas dinâmicos onde posso alterar as cores das classes com js, por exemplo depois de um request no banco de dados.

O exemplo que vou dar é, uma classe que define a cor primária do site, exemplo do meu css:

```
.bg-primary { background-color: black }
```

E gostaria que via JavaScript alterar a classe trocando o `background-color`, pois ele á utilizada por vários elementos. Isso aconteceria após a pagina ja estar carregada, possibilitando trocar o tema apenas clicando em um botão como exemplo:

após a alteração agora a classe ficaria assim

```
.bg-primary { background-color: blue }
```

Obs: Estou construindo isso em um site simples apenas com html/css/js sem nenhum framework para estudos.

é possível? ou preciso abordar este problema de outra forma?

Comment: Você tem que fazer algum código que alterne as configurações, talvez com https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage resolva seu problema. Escrever em .css acho complicado.

Comment: Pensando aqui, agora entendi melhor a tua pergunta: Você queria alterar o conteúdo da classe, certo? Até onde eu sei isso é impossível, o javascript não consegue mudar o arquivo CSS em tempo de execução e talvez mesmo que conseguisse, teríamos que atualizar a página para que o navegador recarregasse o arquivo, então seria algo muito complicado.

Eu sei que é possível ter vários arquivos CSS e fazer o javascript trocar o `href` da tag link que carrega o arquivo CSS. Mas nunca fiz isso.

Comment: @FelipeCarriel é isso mesmo, realmente acredito não ser possível alterar o conteúdo da classe em tempo de execução, vou estudar outra maneira de atacar esse problema

Comment: Acho que o título da pergunta está errado, uma vez que, de acordo com o corpo da pergunta, você não quer mudar uma classe, mas sim uma regra do CSS — a classe mantém-se a mesma `.bg-primary`. _Talvez_ você pode estar complicando as coisas desnecessariamente, visto que isso é _raramente_ necessário.

Comment: Olha isso

aqui https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No processo de pesquisa percebi que não seria possível alterar a classe diretamente em tempo de execução, e é necessário abordar o problema de outra forma.

Uma solução bacana é utilizando váriaves do css e com o javascript setar um valor diferente como abaixo:

```
document.body.style.setProperty('--color-primary', 'green')
```

Assim com js consigo de forma dinâmica alterar as cores por exemplo vindo de um banco de dados.

Vou deixar um exemplo prático:

```js
function trocarCor () {
  document.body.style.setProperty('--color-primary', 'green')
}
```

```css
:root {
  --color-primary: red;
}

.color-primary {
  color: var(--color-primary) !important
}
```

```html
<div class="color-primary">Testando</div>

<button onclick="trocarCor()">Trocar cor</button>
```

Comment: Você pode mudar o conteúdo de uma regra CSS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRule/cssText . Dá uma olhada em `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].cssText` Usando variáveis é a melhor maneira

Answer (score 1):

No JavaScript, uma(s) classe(s) de um elemento HTML é obtida através do atributo `classList` que um objeto do tipo DOMTokenList que pode ser manipulado como um Array de strings.

O atributo classList possui vários métodos, consulte a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Dentre estes métodos, os melor que te servem nesse momento são `add()`, `remove()` e `toggle()`. Veja meu exemplo, espero ter ajudado.

```js
function toggle(){
  document.getElementById("el").classList.toggle('selected')
}
```

```css
p.selected {
  color: blue;
}

p:not(.selected){
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p id="el">Lorem ipsum</p>
<button onClick="toggle()">Toggle</button>
```

Comment: Legal, mas não seria oq eu queria, eu estou precisando alterar a classe em tempo de execução com o js, mas pelo jeito vou precisar abordar de outra forma

Answer (score 1):

Alternativo a [outra reposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/494850/95771), que é uma boa abordagem na minha opinião, você pode, após ter selecionado o elemento do DOM, alterar a propriedade do CSS através do `.style` desse elemento:

```js
function toggle(){
  document.getElementsByClassName("bg-primary")[0].style.backgroundColor = 'blue'
}
```

```css
.bg-primary {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}

p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="bg-primary">
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <button onClick="toggle()">Toggle</button>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

O `document.getElementsByClassName("bg-primary")[0].style.backgroundColor = 'blue'` sobreescreve o valor `black` da propriedade `background-color`.

Comment: Legal, mas eu preciso alterar a classe em tempo de execução pois assim todos que utilizassem sofreria a mudança, mas pelo jeito vou precisar abordar este problema de outra maneira